# Search for an .xls file using FileSystemObject instead of Application.Filesearch

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an existing code done with Office 2003. In the code below, the DO Until searches for a value till End Of ITP and if there is a value it will then search for it in the directory using the Application.Filesearch. Is there a way to achieve search function using FileSystemObject?

```
Dim iTPSheetRef As String
Dim NextForm As String   
Dim QualityFormsPath As String
Dim NextFormLocation As String
Dim AmtDefaultSheets As Integer

Do Until Sheets("ITP Proforma").Cells(6,7) = "<<End of ITP>>"

        'Setting the ITPSheeetRef to the starting cell for the Checksheets
        iTPSheetRef = Sheets("ITP Proforma").Cells(6, 7)

        ' Checking to see whether the next row is blank
        ' If True Then + 1 to the row i.e. go to the following row
        ' If False Then Proceed with opening that particular form
        If Sheets("ITP Proforma").Cells(6, 7) = "" Then
            'True + 1 to the row i.e. go to the following row
            iTPSheetRef = Sheets("ITP Proforma").Cells(6, 8)
        Else
            'False Then Proceed with opening that particular form
            NextForm = iTPSheetRef & ".xls" ' Naming the Quality Sheet File with .xls extension

            'Determining the Path of the respective Quality Sheet
            '----------------------------------------------------

            'Checking out different folders for the default checksheets
            'First check to see whether the respective checksheet is in the Quality Forms Directory
            'i.e. the Default Directory for Quality Checksheets.
            'If not found in the above directory search for the checksheet in the Customs directory.
            'If not found in the Customs directory as well then produce a default checksheet

            'Find whether the respective checksheet is in the "Default" Quality Sheets directory
            With Application.FileSearch
                .NewSearch
                .FileName = NextForm
                .LookIn = QualityFormsPath
                .SearchSubFolders = True

                If .Execute() > 0 Then
                    'True - If the respective Checksheet is found in the "Default" Quality Sheets directory
                    'Then assign the variable NextFormLocation with the path for that particular form
                    For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
                        PathInfo = .FoundFiles(i)
                        NextFormLocation = QualityFormsPath & NextForm
                    Next i
                Else
                    'False - If the respective Checksheet is not found in the "Default" Quality Sheets directory Then
                    'Searach for the checksheet in the customs directory as entered in the Instructions Form
                    .LookIn = CustomsFormsPath
                    .SearchSubFolders = True
                    If .Execute() > 0 Then
                        'True - If the checksheet was found in the Customs Path then
                        'Then assign the variable NextFormLocation with the path for that particular form
                        For j = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
                            PathInfo = .FoundFiles(j)
                            NextFormLocation = CustomsFormsPath & NextForm
                        Next j
                    Else
                        'False - If the checksheet not found in either the "Default" directory or the Customs Directory
                        'Then produce a default blank checksheet
                        ChDir QualityFormsPath
                        NextForm = "a iXXX.xls"
                        NextFormLocation = QualityFormsPath & NextForm
                        AmtDefaultSheets = AmtDefaultSheets + 1
                    End If
                End If
            End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is

```
Sub findfilesindir()

Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim objFile As Scripting.File

For Each objFile In FSO.GetFolder("\\myfolder").Files
    Debug.Print objFile
Next

Set objFile = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Just make you own logic to where I've `Debug.Print`. Default return value of File is file name with path.

Comment: To improve my answer, you can test if single know file exists by using `FSO.FileExists("\\myfilepath.xls")`..

Comment: Good morning! @XealoT

Comment: Good Day @SickDimension, i have used your above method to successfully search for files. Now to step it up to the next level, i am trying to add a function to search files which are entered in a column range. eg in column "F" i will enter the file name and the code needs to search those names in the folder. I have tried few methods but no avail.

Comment: There are couple methods to do this - You can do a for each loop to check all the values for ex. `if r.Value Like objFile.Name then`, or just use the method `FSO.FileExists` to check if there is a file with such name. Id suggest you start a new question thread and post the details what you tried, so it's easier to communicate the issue..

Comment: I have posted another question as requested in the following link:[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844925/search-for-excel-files-in-a-column-range-using-fso]