# Search for Excel Files in a Column Range using FSO

Tags: excel, vba, filesystemobject

In the code below what I am trying to achieve is that the code searches for the files that are entered in column range F in the given path which is "D:\Checksheets\". I am still learning the FSO and would greatly appreciate any help.

```
Sub Test()

Dim FSO As Object
Dim FSO_Folder As Object
Dim FSO_file As Object

Dim path As String


Dim sheetref As String
Dim nextform As String
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer

row = 8
col = 6

sheetref = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col)

'nextform = sheetref

path = "D:\Checksheets\"

Do Until Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(row, col) = "END"

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set FSO_Folder = FSO.GetFolder(path)

    For Each FSO_file In FSO_Folder.Files
        If FSO_file.Name = sheetref Then

        MsgBox "done" & path
    Else

    End If
    row = row + 1
    Next

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the specific question here?

Comment: I want to search files listed in column F in the directory path D:\Checksheets\. Once found display a msgbox File Found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alex I was able to get the code working. In case someone has similar issue, below is the code:

```
Sub test()
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim sht As Worksheet, cell As Range
Dim row As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim path As String

path = "D:\Checksheets\"

row = 1
col = 6
Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")

Do

    Set cell = sht.Cells(row, col)

    If cell.Value = "END" Then Exit Do

    If cell.Value <> "" Then    ' checks for any empty cells

    FSO.FileExists (path)

        MsgBox "file exists"

    Else

    End If



    row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The FSO has a built in `FileExists` method:

```
...
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim sht As Worksheet, cell As Range
Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")

Do
    Set cell = sht.Cells(row, col)

    If cell.Value = "END" Then Exit Do

    If FSO.FileExists(path & cell.Value) Then
        MsgBox "done " & cell.Value
    End If

    row = row + 1
Loop
```

You can remove the FSO code entirely and replace the `FileExists` call with the built-in `Dir$` function:

```
If Len(Dir$(path & cell.Value)) Then
```

Comment: I would not use Dir, if you do things thinking objectively it's just bad way to go.

Comment: @ Alex K. I just modified code to    If FSO.FileExists(path) = cell.Value Then    this way the message box will display the outpout

Comment: @Alex K. If you look at my code, `If FSO.FileExists(path) = cell.Value Then
            MsgBox "file exists"
        Else`                                                      it skips the row and keeps displaying the msgbox for every empty column. do you know where am i going wrong here?

Comment: You mean after "END"? Are there empty cells before the end?

Comment: Yes. at the moment i am entering one file name at row 1,column 6 and END after two empty cells. so the msgbox is displayed twice before exiting the loop.

Comment: Put the FileExists check inside a `if cell.value <> "" then`

Comment: by putting your condition it works. I have added that change in my answer below

Comment: @SickDimension - can you elaborate on why you consider the built in `Dir` function to be a "bad way to go"?  I usually consider built in functions as a better way to go than using functions from an external DLL since the DLL might not exist in another environment, or may be a different version, which can cause odd behavior.  Just curious what your thoughts are on `Dir()`, thanks!